# Merging the Associations of a Parent, its Children and it's Childrens' Children with Rails3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model `Foo`. `Foo` has many children of type `FooChild`. `FooChild` has many `FooChildChild`. `Foo`, `FooChild` and `FooChildChild` all have and belong to many `Bar`. I want to create a method or scope on `Foo` that will return all of the `Bar` associated with it and it's child associations. I currently have something like the following on the `Foo` model.

```
def foo_child_bars
    b = []
    self.foo_childs.includes(:bar).collect{|fc| b += fc.bar}
    b.uniq
end

def foo_child_child_bars
    b = []
    self.foo_childs.includes(:foo_child_childs).collect{|fcc| b += fcc.bar}
    b.uniq
end

def all_bars
    (self.bars + self.foo_child_bars + self.foo_child_child_bars).uniq
end
```

So now I can call `@foo.all_bars` and this works and I don't get duplicates because of the `.uniq` method.

I imagine that this sort of operation is rather inefficient due to the fact that I'm performing three separate queries. Ideally I'd like to do a single query with a `UNION` or something so that the database does the heavy lifting of ensuring only unique records are returned and I'm doing as few queries as possible.

I'm also curious if there is a way to use `includes()` on a nested association such that `foo_child_child_bars()` could include the `:bars` which are associated with all of the `:foo_child_childs` which are being included.

`Bar` in this reduction represents a table `'images'` which has [CarrierWave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) set up on the `Image` model for managing uploaded images. I'm almost positive that there is a gem out there that would probably simplify this whole thing, but I'd rather just make what I have work and tackle that gem implementation later as it will likely involve a lot of complicated table migrations and refactoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two queries

*is Bar polymorphic?*

```
ids = Foo.includes(:foo_children => :foo_child_children).map{|foo| [foo.id, foo.foo_children.map(&:id), foo.foo_children.map(&:foo_child_child).flatten.compact.map(:&id)]}.flatten.compact
Bar.where(:obj_id => ids)
```

Comment: Unfortunately `Bar` is not polymorphic. But I see what you're getting at there. `Foo` is polymorphic. `Foo` has about 4 other classes that inherit from it. I'm thinking that maybe the HABTM relationship for `Bar` ought to be polymorphic. Do you have any suggestions for making that migration?

Comment: Looks like i ought to just do this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations Shame on me for not having done it that way to begin with.